# Issue with function pointer

Tags: c

I'm having a problem with a function pointer that is using the wrong arguments.

The portion of the code which is giving me trouble is this

```
654     for (k = 0; k < o->nk; k++) {
655       val[0] = o->f(o->xyz+3*k, o->constant, o->f_cent, o->f_sig, val+1);
          ...
659     }
```

The goal is to call a series of functions (whose pointers are stored in o->f), each of which is called o->nk times in this loop.

The type of o->f is

```
typedef double (*FLDfunc_t)(double x[], double A, double *ct, double *sig, double grd[]);
```

All functions run correctly, except for the last one (multsinfunc). Output from gdb is:

```
#0  0x000000000048712f in multsinfunc (xyz=0x3923c55, A_in=6.28318530717958, cent_in=0x3568ad7, sig_in=0x3568b6e, grad=0x3243f6a879aff)
at MODELS/fields/functions.c:176
#1  0x00000000004863c2 in do_field_operation (o=0x7fffffffdde0, mdl=0x7ffff7e11010, l=CELL_C, kvar=4, kfrom=0, kto=8)
at MODELS/fields/fields.c:655
```

However, when I go into "do_field_operation", the values for the parameters are different:

```
gdb$ p o->xyz+3*k
$13 = (double *) 0x918150

gdb$ p o->constant
$14 = 1

gdb$ p o->f_cent
$15 = (double *) 0x880130

gdb$ p o->f_sig
$16 = (double *) 0x880148
```

The result is that I get a segmentation fault when I try to access "xyz" in multsinfunc. Maybe this is obvious, but I have no idea why this happens. Everything seems to be declared properly. What could be causing this?

Comment: Maybe `xyz+3*(o->nk-1)` is out of bound. But it's only a guess

Answer (score 1):

You are passing 5 arguments through your call of `o->f`, but - looking at the gdb output - `do_field_operation` has 6 parameters. Calling a function through a function pointer of incorrect type invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: But `do_field_operation` is the one who calls `o->f`.



I think I figured it out. `->` and `()` have the same precedence. Adding some parenthesis around (o->f) seems to fix the problem, though my K&R book says they associate "left to right", so `o->f` should evaluate first anyway. That also doesn't explain why there were no errors with the other function pointers.